# Connect to mongo docker from spark using ssl

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, docker, ssl

For testing purposes I want to connect to a `MongoDB` `docker` instance to `Spark` using the mongo-spark connector.

Setting up the credential for `MongoDB` I use this script to generate all `keys` & `certs` for `SSL` :

```
#Root CA key
openssl genrsa -out rootCA.key 2048

#Root CA crt
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -sha256 -days 1024 -out rootCA.crt -subj "/C=US/ST=CA/L=Santa Monica/O=test/OU=IT/CN=127.0.0.1:27117"

#Mongodb key
openssl genrsa -out mongodb.key 2048

#Mongodb csr
openssl req -new -key mongodb.key -out mongodb.csr -subj "/C=US/ST=CA/L=Santa Monica/O=test/OU=IT/CN=127.0.0.1:27117"

#Mongodb crt
openssl x509 -req -in mongodb.csr -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out mongodb.crt -days 500 -sha256

#PEM files
cat mongodb.key mongodb.crt rootCA.crt > mongodb.pem
cat rootCA.key rootCA.crt > rootCA.pem

# Clean
rm mongo.pkc mongo-truststore

# Add mongo to keystore
openssl pkcs12 -CAfile rootCA.pem -export -in mongodb.pem -out mongo.pkc  -password pass:test12

# Add root ca to trust store
echo "y" | keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -file rootCA.crt -keystore mongo-truststore  -storepass test12
```

Then I run a docker instance :

```
docker run -d \
    --name testmongo \
    -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=test \
    -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=test12 \
    -e MONGODB_DBNAME=testdb \
    -v $sslpath:/etc/ssl/ \
    -p 27117:27017 \
    mongo:3.6 \
    --sslMode requireSSL \
    --sslPEMKeyFile /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem \
    --auth
```

So far so good. I can actually connect to this instance using a tool like 3T `mongochef` using `SSL` & SCRAM (`username` & `password`)

However using `Spark` with these options :

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=local-files/ssl/mongo.pkc -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=test12 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=local-files/ssl/mongo-truststore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=test12 -Djavax.net.debug=true
```

Results in `a` :

> java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present

Complete output :

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateWriteException(InternalStreamConnection.java:465)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:208)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.sendMessage(CommandHelper.java:89)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:32)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:85)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:45)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:116)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:113)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1506)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:747)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.write(SocketStream.java:75)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:204)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchIP(HostnameChecker.java:144)
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:93)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:455)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:436)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:200)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1488)
    ... 16 more
```

Using debug I can actually see that `keystores` are loaded correctly, but somehow the `127.0.0.1` *IP* cannot be matched with a certificate.

I don't want to use `hostnames` since I want to run this on a CI machine at some point.

I've tried both :

```
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER)
```

And :

```
javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
    override def verify(hostname: String, sslSession: SSLSession): Boolean = {
//      hostname == "127.0.0.1"
      true
    }
  })
```

All to no avail :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
The subjectAltName was being checked, but not present in the self signed certificate

Replacing

```
openssl x509 -req -in mongodb.csr -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out mongodb.crt -days 500 -sha256
```

with

```
openssl x509 -req -extfile <(printf "subjectAltName=DNS:localhost,IP:127.0.0.1") -in mongodb.csr -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out mongodb.crt -days 500 -sha256
```

fixed it for me